# Is it risky to use the laptop in the bus? 

Tags: hard-drive

Especially for the laptop's hard drive, due to all the vibrations *while* the hard disk is active?

What about putting laptops in rolling backpacks?

Comment: If you are really worried about it, consider getting a SSD.

Comment: Most newer notebooks have hard drive shock protection software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use laptops while traveling on a bus. However, a huge bump could mess up the platters. They do make shock resistant hard drives now which have definitely saved me in the past. I got a nasty bump on the laptop (ie dropped it while it was booted) and the hard drive immediately realized the shock was beyond the tolerance and shut down. I got a notice on the screen that the drive had taken preventive measures to keep my data safe.

As far as your backpacks go, it would be safe, but I would recommend that you either Shutdown or Hibernate the computer. Do not use sleep mode as it can sometimes keep the disk spinning which is never good for transportation.

Comment: Event a large bump isn't likely to shock it.  Considering it is resting on your lap, its acceleration isn't enough to screw it up. Now if you drop it off your lap. . .

Comment: Oh good points. Does your lap really shield it though? The bus and your lap can pretty much be considered a rigid body with respect to each other (the thing that *might* not be a rigid body is the internal components of the laptop)